# Update multiple databases- mysql

Tags: mysql, multiple-databases

I'm new with mysql.
I have a list of 10 databases with same table structure.
Need to update same table for each database.
Is there any option to do it through phpmyadmin without selecting each database?

or is any function that will be like: USE LIKE `gc%`   ?

Comment: Raw data or table structure?

Comment: Either 10 separate queries or dynamic SQL using.

Answer (score 0):

If its raw data you need to update, make a transaction like this. You cant escape the fact you need 10 different queries.

```
START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE  `db_name1`.`table_01` SET `parameter`=`value` 
    WHERE `parameter`=`value`;
  UPDATE  `db_name2`.`table_01` SET `parameter`=`value` 
    WHERE `parameter`=`value`;
  UPDATE  `db_name3`.`table_01` SET `parameter`=`value` 
    WHERE `parameter`=`value`;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you have multiples databases with same name this is one option.

```
select DISTINCT concat('UPDATE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.content SET ')
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`COLUMNS` c 
where TABLE_NAME = "content" 
  and TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE "c_%";
```

the names of schemas begin with "c_"

Answer (score 0):

You could try a tool like [alphadb](https://github.com/w-kuipers/alphadb). It makes this task simple by using `JSON`. At the time of writing it's still in beta though, better to test it on a non-production database first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35500327)